# PHP image Re-sizer not working for png/gif

Tags: php, image, resize, png, imagecreatefrompng

I'm currently writing a front end for a PHP script(not written by me) that resizes images(PNG,GIF,JPG) and saves them as JPEGs. Its very simple and works fine when inputting JPEGs, but seems not to work for PNG or GIF images.

Here's the code for the resizer:

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$img = $_GET['img'];
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=resized-$img");
$percent = $_GET['percent'];
$constrain = $_GET['constrain'];
$w = $_GET['w'];
$h = $_GET['h'];

// get image size of img
$x = @getimagesize($img);
// image width
$sw = $x[0];
// image height
$sh = $x[1];

if ($percent > 0) {
    // calculate resized height and width if percent is defined
    $percent = $percent * 0.01;
    $w = $sw * $percent;
    $h = $sh * $percent;
} else {
    if (isset ($w) AND !isset ($h)) {
        // autocompute height if only width is set
        $h = (100 / ($sw / $w)) * .01;
        $h = @round ($sh * $h);
    } elseif (isset ($h) AND !isset ($w)) {
        // autocompute width if only height is set
        $w = (100 / ($sh / $h)) * .01;
        $w = @round ($sw * $w);
    } elseif (isset ($h) AND isset ($w) AND isset ($constrain)) {
        // get the smaller resulting image dimension if both height
        // and width are set and $constrain is also set
        $hx = (100 / ($sw / $w)) * .01;
        $hx = @round ($sh * $hx);

        $wx = (100 / ($sh / $h)) * .01;
        $wx = @round ($sw * $wx);

        if ($hx < $h) {
            $h = (100 / ($sw / $w)) * .01;
            $h = @round ($sh * $h);
        } else {
            $w = (100 / ($sh / $h)) * .01;
            $w = @round ($sw * $w);
        }
    }
}

$im = @ImageCreateFromJPEG ($img) or // Read JPEG Image
$im = @ImageCreateFromPNG ($img) or // or PNG Image
$im = @ImageCreateFromGIF ($img) or // or GIF Image
$im = false; // If image is not JPEG, PNG, or GIF

if (!$im) {
    // We get errors from PHP's ImageCreate functions...
    // So let's echo back the contents of the actual image.
    readfile ($img);
} else {
    // Create the resized image destination
    $thumb = @ImageCreateTrueColor ($w, $h);
    // Copy from image source, resize it, and paste to image destination
    @ImageCopyResampled ($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $sw, $sh);
    // Output resized image
    @ImageJPEG ($thumb);

}
?>
```

Can you see any reason why the png/gif options are not working? 
I have GD up-to-date and enabled for all formats and am running php 5.3.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try with one of those format? Try removing the @ symbol in front and let us know what error you get.

Comment: in chrome i get webpage not available 'Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.' firefox says 'The connection was reset'  Removing the '@' has no effect

Comment: I tested it with "?w=20&h=20&img=1.png", it worked for the PNG file. Whats your query string?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? I read that some anti-virus software can cause that too. Otherwise, there may be a problem with your code that's causing the connection to reset. I'm not the biggest fan of the `imagecreatefromjpeg() or imagecreatefromgif() or ...`. You should see my answer below. It might not solve your problem but it'll be more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third item of your `$x` array from the `getimagesize()` contains the mime-type of the image. You should use it instead of using the `or` statement and trying all types.

```
switch ( $x[2] ) 
{
  case 1: $im = imagecreatefromgif($img); break;
  case 2: $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($img); break;
  case 3: $im = imagecreatefrompng($img); break;
  default: trigger_error('Unsupported filetype!', E_USER_WARNING);  break;
}
```

Comment: I had assumed it was a mime-type problem, this has fixed it. As the original code was not mine I dint know where to start! Very fast and helpful reply, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($img))` instead of that hideous construct of yours. Or do a proper switch statement and explicitly determine which one to use instead of trying each in turn.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Francois Deschenes allready said... Please remove all those `@` and turn error reporting on (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`). You supressed so much sources of possible errors, that it is nearly impossible to debug this script yourself. Try to write scripts that don't even use a single `@` anywhere...